# Can this question be solved without any calculation?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, statistical-mechanics, newtonian-gravity, astrophysics, stars

I came across this question on YouTube:
[image]

The formal solution to both models can be done by integration (the solution can be found here: https://youtu.be/cSjVEKVV1ls). After calculation the ratio of Kinetic Energy (KE) to Total energy (TE) for both models comes out to be -1. KE/TE = -1 is a characteristic property of any particle performing circular motion under a force that follows inverse square law (F∝r^-2) for example satellites orbiting under gravitational force or atoms in Bohr's Model.  Since all the forces here are also inverse square type forces could we have given the answer without any calculation?

Answer (score 0):

I think that this question can be done without actual solving. Here's what I think is happening. In Model 1, in the formal solution, we are considering a particle of mass dm in a shell of radius r(<R) and thickness dr. We can consider this dm mass as a satellite so for this particle KE/TE=-1, we can also say that its potential energy(PE) = -2KE and the integration of this PE over the sphere gives the Self Energy and the integration of KE gives well KE for the whole sphere. So for the whole sphere the ration must also be -1. Same for model 2

Comment: This does assume that you have seen (sometime in the past) a calculation that shows that the potential energy of a satellite in a circular orbit is negative and is twice the kinetic energy.

Answer (score 0):

I would think that in the second case a calculation would be required to show that the increase in potential energy as the gas expands with increasing temperature is proportional to the corresponding increase in kinetic energy.